# Errors while Using map functions in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

Im trying to display some data using map function but im keep on getting warnings and errors.
 they are

**Warning: There is an internal error in the React performance measurement code. Did not expect componentDidMount timer to start while render timer is still in progress for another instance.**

and the other one is

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined**

i found out that **this.props.courses.map** returns null but i still cant figure out why?

```
import React,{PropTypes} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import * as courseActions from '../actions/courseActions';


class CoursesPage extends React.Component{

    constructor(props,context){
       super(props,context);

       this.state={
         course:[{id:1,title:'hello'}]
       };

       this.onTitleChange = this.onTitleChange.bind(this);
       this.onClickSave = this.onClickSave.bind(this);

    }

    onTitleChange(event){
      const course = this.state.course;
      course.title = event.target.value;
      this.setState({course:course});
    }

    onClickSave(){
       this.props.dispatch(courseActions.createCourse(this.state.course));
    }

    courseRow(){
      return this.props.courses.map((course)=>{
          return(
            <div key={course.id}>{course.title}</div>
          );
      });
    }

    render(){
      return(
        <div>
          <h2>hello</h2>
          <h3>{this.courseRow()}</h3>
          <input type="text" onChange={this.onTitleChange} value={this.state.course.title}/>
          <input type="submit" value="save" onClick={this.onClickSave}/>
        </div>
      );
    }

}

CoursesPage.propTypes ={
   dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
   courses: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

function mapStateToProps(state,ownProps){
     return{
        courses:state.courses
     };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CoursesPage);
```

here is my reducer

```
export default function courseReducer(state = [],action){
    switch(action.type){
       case 'CREATE_USER':
         state.push(action.user);
          return [...state,Object.assign({},action.user)];
         default:
          return state;
      }
}
```

my rootReducer

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import users from './userReducer';
import courses from './courseReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  users:users,
  courses:courses
});

export default rootReducer;
```

the store

```
import {createStore,applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import rootReducer from '../reducers/rootReducer';

export default function configureStore(initialState){
  return createStore(
     rootReducer,
     initialState
   );
}
```

Comment: you have a typo this.state.course is defined but "courses" is not.

Comment: @JustinHerter sorry it should be this.props.courses.map but still getting the same error

Comment: ??? props.courses is not an array otherwise .map would be defined. console.log("props: ",props) in your constructor to see whats there.

Comment: Can you share you store/reducers? The courses which is being read of store is null or undefined because of which you are getting this error. Posting relevant code really would help

Comment: @HarkiratSaluja ok ive edited my question

Comment: BTW you should not be doing `state.push(action.user)` in the `case CREATE_USER`. If you do so you are adding the user twice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Redux store's `courses` might be `undefined` at the start and hence `this.props.courses` becomes `undefined`. Trying to access `.map` of `undefined` will give you the error you mentioned above. There are a few ways to fix this:

**Approach 1 (Recommended):** Set the initial value of the `state.courses` to empty array `[]` in your the reducer. Refer to the documentation on Reducers to see how to set an initial state: http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html.

**Approach 2:** Set a default value for `props.courses` in `mapStateToProps`.

```
function mapStateToProps(state,ownProps){
  return {
    courses: state.courses || []
  };
}
```

**Approach 3:** Check that `this.props.courses` is not `undefined` or `null` before rendering it:

```
courseRow() {
  if (!this.props.courses) {
    return null;
  }

  return this.props.courses.map((course)=>{
    return(
      <div key={course.id}>{course.title}</div>
    );
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your reducer where are you updating courses?? I can only see users from the code you posted.

```
 const initialState = {
        courses : [],
 }



export default function courseReducer(state =initialState,action){
    switch(action.type){
       //create a course or update it , else value is 
       //undefined and your map would throw error.
       case 'CREATE_COURSES':
         return Object.assign({},state,{
                 courses : action.user}
          );
         default:
          return state;
      }
}
```

Also in your render method you need to check if this value is filled then only run map.

```
 <h3>{this.props.courses.length > 1 ? this.courseRow() : null}</h3>
```

Comment: I'm afraid this is incorrect. His `combineReducers` is fine, `users: users` is simply the longer version of `users`. Secondly, courses is an array but you are returning an object in `courseReducer`.

Comment: yeah here i am returning the state object right.. courses is an array in state object so i guess it should be fine.

Comment: @HarkiratSaluja  now im getting an error as 
Reducer "courses" returned undefined during initialization. If the state passed to the reducer is undefined, you must explicitly return the initial state. The initial state may not be undefined.

Comment: have yo u added default to your switch statement?

Comment: `this.props.courses.length > 1` will still run into the same problem if `this.props.courses` is `undefined`. @TRomesh please give my suggestions a try.

Comment: that obvious.. iniitialize courses to an empty entry as default  @TRomesh.. update the answer

Answer (score 3):

After modifying the code with the help of both @Harkirat Saluja and @Yang Shun. i manages to fix the issue which was initializing courses so i changed my Reducer as below

**state = []** did the trick!

```
 export default function courseReducer(state = [],action){
        switch (action.type) {
          case 'CREATE_COURSE':
                return [...state,Object.assign({},action.course)];
           default:
            return state;

        }
    }
```

Comment: happy to help :) . Can you please accept the answer?

Answer (score 2):

Your `mapStateToProps` is returning a reducer instead of actual `props` that you can use right away. It should probably look like this:

```
function mapStateToProps(state,ownProps){
     return{
        ...state.courses
     };
}
```